# What is the difference between declaring @Autowired and declaring bean in the application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I build the spring project1 of module1 as a jar file, then added this jar file dependency in another module2 of project2, then the module2 is added in the project3. Now, while starting the tomcat service getting the error as NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for Module1 class object.

While checking with module2 code found injected module1 class object using @Autowired annotation, By including the bean declaration in xml (`<bean id="object" class="claspackage"/>`. Issue has been fixed. but I am unable to find the root cause for this, how the bean functionality got differs?

Comment: You are probably missing a @ComponentScan for the given package.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce included   <context:component-scan base-package="module1Classpage" /> in project3 application context but it's not working. Any difference in functionality by using Autowired and injecting the bean in xml. Up to my knowledge Autowired will automatically create the bean why it's not affected in project3 but its effect in project2.

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="xxx" />. xxx has to be the full package name (e.g. com.myprojet.submodule) where the component that's autowired is defined (e.g. com.myprojet.submodule.Module1Bean).

Comment: @JihedAmine com.myprojet.submodule means ?.Example: I am having the module1 of project1 package as "org.example.com.project1.module1.sampleClassPackage". now what should I include for component scan in project3.
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example.com.project1.module1.sampleClassPackage" /> this one not worked for project3 but worked for project2.

Comment: correct. Maybe it worked for project2 because project2's injected class is in org.example.com.project1.module1.sampleClassPackage. So you'd have to add another . <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.com.project1.module2.sampleClassPackage" /> supposing module2's component that gets injected in module3 is defined under org.example.com.project1.module2.sampleClassPackage